# String to Dict Conversion and %0a -

Tags: string, dictionary, linefeed

I am trying to convert a string to dict and for some reason, `%0a` gets added. Tried converting using ast and JSON modules with no luck.
The strings are read from a file. Below is a sample record:

```
{"description" : "GA", "ip" : "10.145.133.4", "username" : "admin", "password" : "admin", "lol" : "lol", "lol_u" : "j", "lol_p" : "pass", "owner" : []}
```

The `%0a` is added to the IP address as follows:

```
host='10.145.133.4%0a'
```

And that change messes up the program.

Any ideas why this is happening and how fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you possibly paste a few lines from your input file?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

Comment: The input file contains lines just like I provided above. I am providing the error messsage that is issued by urllib3:

Comment: urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.145.133.14%0a', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /csrf (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1931ad3710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

Please note that %0a at the end of the IP address

Comment: This doesn't make sense.. your input has `ip` and your output has `host` ...

Comment: 'ip' is the variable that I use, 'host' is internal I guess.

Comment: I believe I found the bug that was causing the issue. Thanks for looking into this.